# Decipher Writing (Philadelphia Street Address)

Tags: palaeography, manifest

Trying to decipher this Philadelphia Street address from early 1900's.

1622 Cambria St Phila
or
1622 Caroline St Phila

There's another address on the manifest [(5th from bottom)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz7fc.png) that looks similar and is spelled 'Cambrio', but there is only a Cambria St in Philadelphia.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/zPAhYvn.png]

THANKS for help.

Comment: 1946 Street C Index http://i.imgur.com/Cun662n.jpg 1859 Street C Index http://i.imgur.com/WAslVC8.png

Comment: Are you sure it is 1622 rather than 1699?  My untrained eye agrees with "Cambria".

Comment: Can you find the friend / relative in contemporary city directories or the nearest census?

Answer (score 5):

I am by no means an expert, but I would say it is *Cambria St* .

First, off there are the wrong number of strokes for it to be Caroline. There is the obvious *C* and *a*, then the *r* and *o*. So far so good, but after the *l*, there is the *i*, *n*, an extra stroke and an *e*. (Assuming for the sake of illustration it says *Caroline*). That extra stroke doesn't make sense in there as part of the *n* or *e*. However, the strokes perfectly match *Cambria*.

Also, the character between the *a* and the tall letter (*l* / *b*) could not be an *r* and an *o*. The *o* doesn't come together on the bottom at all.

Comparing it to the surrounding handwriting also lends to the Cambria theory. Notice the similarities between the *n* in this entry and the *n* above in *Highland  Ave*, *Brother John*, and *Cleveland*.

Of these reasons, the strongest is the first, but I think they all further prove that it says *Cambria St Phila* .

Answer (score 3):

When trying to decipher handwriting like this it is useful to have a larger sample to work with. This enables looking at other entries and confirming how individual letter are written. It can also help to invert the image.

I am not so certain that it is in fact Cambria as suggested by others looking at the inverted image. As above I would like to see a larger sample of the page before commenting further on what I think it is.

[image: Inverted original image scan]

Comment: Here's the other address on the page:http://i.imgur.com/Bm166AU.png